# Random forest classifier metrics rdd

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

Looking for Random forest classifier metrics like ROC, precision recall curve, precision, recall, F1 score based on Dataframe using pyspark. I could get the same metrics on RDD object.Could someone pls help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to compute the ML metrics but on Spark dataframes?
You could just transform the final dataframe into an rdd and use the existing metric functions for rdd.
For example:

```
 from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

 predictions = model.transform(some_data_in_dataframe)
 labels_and_predictions = predictions.select("prediction","true_label").rdd

 metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(labels_and_predictions)
 print((metrics.areaUnderPR * 100))
 print((metrics.areaUnderROC * 100))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! You are correct! I want the ML metrics based on dataframes.  Below are the few metrics, we can compute for RDD based. I would like to know,  how we can achieve the same from dataframe.

# Overall statistics
precision = metrics.precision()
recall = metrics.recall()
f1Score = metrics.fMeasure()
print("Summary Stats")
print("Precision = %s" % precision)
print("Recall = %s" % recall)
print("F1 Score = %s" % f1Score)

Comment: Can anyone pls advise on below?

Comment: hello Selva, As said above, you do not need metrics for a data frame. After you bring your data to the needed state in the dataframe you just turn them to an RDD and you compute what you need.
the code I pasted you in my answer does exactly that thing with the ".rdd"

Comment: Thanks Zulthar! I understand now, we can't compute the metrics directly from dataframe, rather need to convert the dataframe into RDD before metrics computations.